# How to pass the navigator object to the components used in the react natives root file?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Below is my app component:

```
/**
 * Class app from where the app bootstraps
 */
export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  // This is where all your routes will be processed
  renderScene(route, navigator) {
    // Set a variable to get the route
    let RouteComponent = route.component;

    _navigator = navigator;

    // With props return the components
    return (
      <RouteComponent navigator={navigator} {...route.passProps} />
    );
  }

  static navigationBarRouteMapper = openControlPanel => ({
      LeftButton: function(route, navigator, index, navState) {
        return (

          // Hamburger icon which on clicked opens the menu
          <TouchableOpacity style={navBarStyle.left} onPress={() => openControlPanel()}>
            <View>
              {hamburgerIcon}
            </View>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        );
      },
      RightButton: function(route, navigator, index, navState) {
        return (
          // cart menu
          <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => dismissKeyboard()}>
            <View style={navBarStyle.right}>
              {cartIcon}
              <View style={navBarStyle.counter}>
                <Text style={navBarStyle.counterText}>20</Text>
              </View>
            </View>
          </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
        );
      },
      Title: function(route, navigator, index, navState) {
        // Title of the route
        return (
          <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => dismissKeyboard()}>
            <View style={navBarStyle.titleWrap}>
              <Text style={navBarStyle.title}>{route.title.toUpperCase()}</Text>
            </View>
          </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
        );
      }
  })

  // Close the menu drawer
  closeControlPanel() {
    this._drawer.close();
  }

  // open the menu drawer
  openControlPanel() {
    this._drawer.open();
    dismissKeyboard();
  }

  // On clicking the menu item, this function routes to that menu item page
  getNavigator(route) {
    this.refs.navigator.replace(route);
    this.closeControlPanel();
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <Drawer
        ref={ (ref) => { this._drawer = ref; } }
        type="overlay"
        content={<Menu navigator={this.getNavigator.bind(this)} menuItems={menu} closeControlPanel={this.closeControlPanel.bind(this)} />}
        onOpenStart={() => dismissKeyboard()}
        tapToClose={true}
        openDrawerOffset={0.2}
        panCloseMask={0.2}
        panOpenMask={20}
        acceptPan={true}
        closedDrawerOffset={-3}
        styles={drawerStyle}
        tweenHandler={(ratio) => ({

          // This code will maintain the opacity for main
          // Whilst the opacity for the mainOverlay on the screen will be faded.
          main: { opacity: 1 },
          mainOverlay: {
            opacity: ratio / 2,
            backgroundColor: 'black',
          }

        })}>

        <Navigator
          initialRoute={homeScene}
          renderScene={this.renderScene}
          ref="navigator"
          // Navbar of the app
          navigationBar={
            <Navigator.NavigationBar
              routeMapper={App.navigationBarRouteMapper(this.openControlPanel.bind(this))}
              style={navBarStyle.navBar}
            />
          }
        />

        <EditSearch />
      </Drawer>
    );
  }
}
```

At the very bottom you'll see the `<EditSearch>` component which contains two text inputs. This component would be common to all the pages in the app except the home page.

Hence, I wanna know on which page or scene am I currently on so that I could check whether the scene/page is the home page or not. If it's the home page I would hide the component else I would show it for all other pages.

I tried passing the navigator via ref like so:

```
<EditSearch nav={this.refs.navigator} />
```

But, I get undefined on the `<EditSearch>` component and the view doesn't re-render when the page changes as it doesn't detect any state change.

I can do something like:

```
this.state = {
  currentRoute: 'home'
}
```

And then change this state when route changes. But, I cannot change state within renderScene as setting state in renderScene will lead into infinite loop. If I could set this state with the title of the page when route changes, I could then send that state to `<EditSearch>` component.

I am pretty confused how can I pass current route information to this common component. Thanks in anticipation.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found a solution but I am unsure if it's appropriate.

So below is my solution.

First I created the state and function to set that state:

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      isHome: false
    };

    this.setIsHome = this.setIsHome.bind(this);
  }

  setIsHome(flag) {
    // Set state to let component know whether the page is home or not
    this.setState({
      isHome: flag ? flag : false
    });
  }
```

Then passed the function to all the pages where those pages can either hide or show `<EditSearch>` component:

```
<RouteComponent navigator={navigator} {...route.passProps} setIsHome={this.setIsHome} />
```

Then I passed the `isHome` state to the `<EditSearch>` component:

```
<EditSearch isHome={ this.state.isHome } />
```

And this is how I call the function in the home component:

```
  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.setIsHome(true);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.props.setIsHome(false);
  }
```

This is how I show/hide the component. I hope it's helpful. But, would be really nice to know how to pass navigator object to such components.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution from Drawer Github issues.

> Found a quick workaround for this but it is not ideal. If you wrap the
>   Navigator with the Drawer component, then inside of the
>   Navigator.NavigationBar you can set this.navigator = this.navigator ||
>   navigator and then you can pass the navigator to your content
>   component for the Drawer.
>
> ```
> <Drawer
>   content={<Main navigator={this.navigator}/>}
>   type='overlay'>
>
>   <Navigator
>     renderScene={renderScene}
>     navigationBar={
>
>       <Navigator.NavigationBar
>         routeMapper={{
>           LeftButton: (route, navigator, index, navState) => {
>
>             this.navigator = this.navigator || navigator;
>
>             return (
>               <View>
>                 <Text>Something</Text>
>               </View>
>             );
>           }
>         }}
>       />
>   />
> </Drawer>
> ```

https://github.com/root-two/react-native-drawer/issues/187#issuecomment-231461585